# Number of polyhedra covering a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, combinatorics, general-topology, optimization

Let's assume we have a ball of radius $r$
$$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2 \leq r\}$$
For now, we can fix $r=1$.

We further assume to have $n$-line equations
$$a_{i1}x+a_{i2}+b_i=0 \quad \forall i =1,...,n \quad a_{i1},a_{i2},b_i \in \mathbb{R}$$

These lines intersect and give rise to $N$ polyhedra with
$$N \leq \binom{n}{0}+\binom{ n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}$$

We require that each line intersects the ball.

---

The question is the following: What is the maximum number of polyhedral such that none of them intersect the ball for a given $n$ (keep in mind all lines have to intersect the ball)?

[image]
In this picture on the left, there are 5 polyhedra without intersecting the ball. In contrast on the left, all intersect the ball.

---

This question has some follow-up questions. I would be happy if the answer could incorporate them but I could also open up a new question.

- What is the mathematical area called which deals with these problems?
- I think there is a maximal radius $R>r$ such that there can't be intersections outside this radius. I.e. we can't move these polyhedral infinitely far away. Is this correct?
- Are there configurations such that all polyhedra intersect the ball for all $n$?

Comment: (1) Polyhedra are three-dimensional, I think you mean to say "polygons". (2) The maximum number of polygonal regions is $\binom n2-\binom n1+\binom n0$. It is true that $n$ lines will divide the plane into $\binom n2+\binom n1+\binom n0$ regions, but $2n$ of these regions will be infinite, so I would not call them polygons.

Comment: You can always arrange for the bounded regions to be away from the ball. Just make the lines almost parallel in a way that all the intersections are away from the ball in the same direction and use that each bounded region is the convex hull of some of the intersection points.